# how do i line up three posts in a row dynamically?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a grid portfolio page using Bootstrap 2.3.2 that automatically pulls my posts.

I want the grid to be 3 images wide. For some reason it seems to work but the images and post content does not all align properly once it passed row one.

Below is the picture (with red boxes representing my posts featured image) followed by the code. [image]

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Design Porftolio
*/
?>

<?php

remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');
add_action('genesis_loop', 'custom_loop');

function custom_loop() {
$args = array ('designtype'=>'websitedesigns');
query_posts ($args);
?>

<div class="well">
<h2>Portfolio: Web Design & Development</h2>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<div class="span4">


     <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(336,190)); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
     ![enter image description here][1]
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You should perhaps try making a row for each row of content. Are you doing that ? Each row class wraps around columns, so if you n rows, you will need n classes with the row class to wrap around your columns

Comment: my code is shown above. I am using fluid rows and span4's for my entry.